# How do I concatenate a string to a variable declaration in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, concatenation, declaration, variable-declaration

I wonder if it is possible to concatenate a variable value or a string to a new variable value declaration in Ruby.

```
foo = "something"
#new variable declaration:
var_ + foo = "concat variable name"
p var_foo   # => "concat variable name"

n = 2
position + n = Array.new(3, 1)
p position2    # => [1, 1, 1]`
```

Thank you very much

Comment: In general you can't. There are `Binding#local_variable_set/`/`local_variable_set`, but this is not exactly what you are looking for. Why do you need it?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov it's just a doubt to know if it can be done like in other languages like php. I am new in Ruby

Comment: You can create instance variables dynamically (i.e. generate the variable name dynamically), and you can use `eval`, but but both approaches make the code hard to maintain. My feeling is that you have here a [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Even in PHP, I don't see why you would want to do this for a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a scenario it's probably better to use a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html) instead.

```rb
values = {}
values['foo'] = 'something'
values['var_' + 'foo'] = 'concat variable name'

p values['var_foo'] #=> "concat variable name"

n = 2
values["position#{n}"] = Array.new(3, 1)
p values['position2'] #=> [1, 1, 1]
```